# How to add scroll-end hightlight to SurfaceView?

Tags: android, scroll, surfaceview

In my application I have a SurfaceView with dynamically created image. This image can be scrolled inside SurfaceView. Inside SurfaceView's drawing thread I know size of the image and I disable scrolling when it touch the boundaries. Also I want to highlight one of the side of SurfaceView when scrolling touch this boundary (like in ListView). How to implement this?

Comment: what you mean by highlight?

Comment: Take any application with listview or gridview and try to scroll this list to the end. You will see yellow, blue or white highlight on the bottom side of this list.

Comment: see View.java https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java look for "fadingedge"

Comment: Thank you for info! But I see only the initialization here. It called from another place? Is I can just call it or I need to implement my own hightlighting?

Comment: i think ListView somehow triggers it on, but didnt have time to analise it

Comment: Okay, thank you) I will trying to understand it.